# Error Propagation from Linear Programming Constraints. Given $Ax = b$, $x \ge 0$, and $Cov(b)$, what is variance of $\min x_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, linear-programming

Given $Ax = b$, $x \ge 0$, and the covariance matrix $Cov(b)$, what is variance of $\min  x_i$? Could there be an analytical solution?

$x_i$ is the $i$-th element of $x$. $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix where $m < n$, an $A$ is $m$-rank. Also, we can assume the variance of $b_i$ and $b_j$ are independent, so $Cov(b)$ is a diagonal matrix.